# Comparing type discovered through reflection with referenced type in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

End goal: I'm implementing a server application and protocol, and would like to allow for a plugin ability to handle any number of request commands. To do this, I am creating an interface in a dll (we'll call it IHandler). Other users will reference this and implement the interface to create their various handlers. For example: `public class BlergHandler : IHandler`

The dlls they create will be placed in a common directory, and at startup the server app will load all of the dlls through reflection. When a request comes in, it will spin up the required handler and pass on the request.

The problem I'm encountering is that I'm having trouble determining whether or not the types I find using reflection implement the interface or not. I *believe* the issue has to do with comparing the type interfaces loaded through reflection with a directly referenced interface. Here is the code I am using for the time being:

```
var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(filename);

foreach (Type type in DLL.GetExportedTypes())
{
  // dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  if (!type.IsInterface)
  {
    Console.Write("Found: " + type.Name);
    if (type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IHandler)))
    {
      Console.Write("  : IHandler (contains check)");
    }
    
    if (typeof(IHandler).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
      Console.Write("  : IHandler (assignable check)");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(""); // For cleanliness
  }
}
```

The above checks fail even though the types found implement the interface in question. I also confirmed that if I directly reference the dll, the checks pass. e.g. `TestHandler.GetInterfaces().Contains(IHandler)` is true.

I hope I did a good job of explaining what I want to happen, and what is actually happening. I have to be missing something simple, but I'm stuck. Thanks in advance you glorious wizards!

**Solution that worked for me:**

After digging around, it seems the issue was related to implementing my test handlers in the same project as the IHandler interface. .NET seems to not equate the version of the dll directly referenced in my app with the same dll loaded using reflection.

My solution was to make the IHandler interface dll it's own library, and implement my test handlers in yet another dll (this is more in tune with the end goal anyway). My project and the handlers dll both reference the IHandler interface, but the handlers dll is no longer directly referenced by my app.

I'm going to leave this open a bit to try the solution referenced by @DevRacker. I'm using an older version of .NET (not 5.0), so I'm not sure it'll work for my case.

Comment: This is .net framework? What version?

Comment: Maybe you are doing it the other way around. Did you try doing `type.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IHandler))`?

Comment: @DevRacker Yes, .NET Framework 4.7.2, though I'm not married to any particular version.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach of comparing types is not the best approach in this scenario, it is best to compare names as strings and confirm it by using `Activator.CreateInstance()`.

This is your code updated to do this (using .NET 5):

```
var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"");
foreach (Type type in DLL.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (!type.IsInterface)
    {
        Console.Write("Found: " + type.Name);
        if (type.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.AssemblyQualifiedName == typeof(IHandler).AssemblyQualifiedName))
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IHandler;
            if (instance != null)
            {
                Console.Write("  : IHandler (contains check)");
            }
        }            
        Console.WriteLine(""); // For cleanliness
    }
}
```

You can use the `AssemblyQualifiedName` or the `Name`, it all on whether the version must be the same or not.
The Activator ensures that you were able to create an instance of the class as that interface, which is 100% safe, since the instance can not be created otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try. I actually found *a* solution while digging around a bit more and messing with stuff. I was directly referencing the IHandler project, but also implemented some "default" handlers and loading the dll at runtime. For some reason, it seems .NET was "seeing" this as two separate interfaces.